# Error when defining field types on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm getting an error on RoR that I can't seem to fix yet, it is the following:

I have my form setup like this

```
<%= form_for @sheet, url: '/sheets#new' do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      Inicio:<br>
                      <%= f.datetime_field_tag :Inicio %>
                      Fim: <br>
                      <%= f.datetime_field_tag :Fim %><br>
                      Tarefa:<br>
                      <%= f.number_field_tag :Tarefa %><br>  
                      PNA:<br>
                      <%= f.number_field_tag :PNA %><br>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">

                      FPNA:<br>
                      <%= f.number_field_tag :FPNA %><br>
                      Deslocação:<br>
                      <%= f.number_field_tag :Deslocacao %><br>
                      KM's:<br>
                      <%= f.number_field_tag :km %><br>
                      Estadia:<br>
                      <%= f.number_field_tag :estadia %><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="text">
                      Descrição:<br>
                        <div class="textfield">
                            <%= f.text_field_tag :descricao %><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
        <% end %>
```

and when I try to submit anything I get the following error:

```
undefined method `datetime_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xd13f898>
```

If for example I take out the f. on the fiels it works but it posts every field as "null" on the database, help/ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try f.datetime_field

Comment: it worked, thanks! make a response so I can accept it please

Comment: remove all the _tag from field because you mapped it with form and rails gives a object which consist these field

Comment: Just FYI, if you add "_tag" in a form_for, it just renders a field without giving it a name so Rails won't know that you need to save it

Comment: @xdmanmagiconsei Sure, I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [datetime_field](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/datetime_field) with form_for instead of [datetime_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/datetime_field_tag)